# Why i can not call the web service in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm new in c# and want too call the bank web service,in bank document write this:
call the `BatchBillPaymentRequest` method with `ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData` object for input argumant :

```
BatchBillPaymentRequest(ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData data)
```

for that purpose write this class:

```
class ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData
    {
        public string CallbackUrl { get; set; }
        public string LoginAccount { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string BillId { get; set; }
        public string PayId { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalData { get; set; }
    }
```

and write this code:

```
payment.BillService behzad=new BillService();
            ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData datas = new ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData();
            datas.BillId = "1233";
            datas.CallbackUrl = "google.com";
            datas.LoginAccount = "213214";
            datas.OrderId = 123;
            datas.PayId = "2131243";
            datas.AdditionalData = "23213";
            behzad.BatchBillPaymentRequest(datas);
```

but in this line:

```
behzad.BatchBillPaymentRequest(datas);
```

get this error:
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ConsoleApplication1.ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData' to 'ConsoleApplication1.payment.ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData'  ConsoleApplication1 L:\TEMP\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  23  Active
```

what happen?how can i solve that problem?thanks.
VS add this class too project:

```
public ClientBatchBillPaymentResponseData BatchBillPaymentRequest(ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData requestData) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("BatchBillPaymentRequest", new object[] {
                        requestData});
            return ((ClientBatchBillPaymentResponseData)(results[0]));
        }
```

Comment: Because VS already added a class `ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData` with all the required properties when you added the reference to the web server. You do not need to write your own one. Just use `ConsoleApplication1.payment.ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData` (as you're already doing with `BillService`)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti what your means you do not need to write your own one?

Comment: That when you added a reference to that Web Service Visual Studio already generated that class for you (as it generated the `BillService` class). Just delete your class and use `var datas = new payment.ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData();`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thanks bot how can pass data to that method on web service?in document say want BatchBillPaymentRequest(ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData data)

Comment: That class contains all the properties the web service knows about. You do not need to change anything else (assuming names match) but to create an instance of the _right_ type. Just try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Adriano Repetti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1207195/adriano-repetti)'s comment - when you added the web service reference Visual Studio created a class for you to use - so change this code from this

```
payment.BillService behzad=new BillService();
ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData datas = new ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData();
datas.BillId = "1233";
datas.CallbackUrl = "google.com";
datas.LoginAccount = "213214";
datas.OrderId = 123;
datas.PayId = "2131243";
datas.AdditionalData = "23213";
behzad.BatchBillPaymentRequest(datas);
```

to this

```
payment.BillService behzad=new BillService();
var datas = new ConsoleApplication1.payment.ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData();
datas.BillId = "1233";
datas.CallbackUrl = "google.com";
datas.LoginAccount = "213214";
datas.OrderId = 123;
datas.PayId = "2131243";
datas.AdditionalData = "23213";
behzad.BatchBillPaymentRequest(datas);
```

You can streamline this a little by doing this instead too

```
payment.BillService behzad=new BillService();
var datas = new ConsoleApplication1.payment.ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData{
    BillId = "1233",
    CallbackUrl = "google.com",
    LoginAccount = "213214",
    OrderId = 123,
    PayId = "2131243",
    AdditionalData = "23213"
}
behzad.BatchBillPaymentRequest(datas);
```

You should also remove the `ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData` class you created as its surplus to requirements.

For each of the Attributes in your object instantiation, highlight it and press `CTRL-Space` to get autocomplete to correctly case your parameter name.

If you don't know the structure of your Webservice call you can use Wizdler for Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wizdler/oebpmncolmhiapingjaagmapififiakb?hl=en to find out what the packets should be .

Once you install it, enter the `WSDL` URL in chrome, click the wizdler button to the right of the address bar and select the method you want to call, this will let you see the parameters (including their names and casing).

[image: https://forgetfulprogrammer.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/wizdler.png]

Comment: thanks my friend but when write your code in my project get this error:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData' does not contain a definition for 'PayId' and no extension method 'PayId' accepting a first argument of type 'ClientBatchBillPaymentRequestData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ConsoleApplication1 L:\TEMP\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 20 Active

Comment: Does it compile? does your Webservice provide the same attribute values as your code had? is PayID a return value rather than something you set on post? you can always try using Wisdler to figure out what your webservice requests and whether you have the right casing on the object.

Comment: Please wait my friend

Comment: add payment web service on the my project my question this,how can i see BatchBillPaymentRequest method structure ?